# Apache Redirecting Undefined Domains and Default Site

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to figure this one out. I have several sites hosted on Ubuntu 14.04/LAMP and I have a .conf file for each domain I'm hosting.

However, if someone enters a non-existent subdomain, for example, of one of the sites on the server, apache just redirects you to a random site (seems to find the first .conf file in /etc/apache/sites-enabled in alphabetical order).

When I have a site only configured for `<VirtualHost *:80>` (non-SSL) and someone (like a Google bot) requests the https version of this site, they are redirected to the first .conf file with `<VirtualHost *:443>` rules defined.

How can I prevent this? I just want everyone to land on an error page if a subdomain of a given domain doesn't exist, or if the non-https version of the site doesn't exist (since, apparently you can't redirect https to http).

Is there something specific I can put in 000-default.conf and 000-default-ssl.conf to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: set up a wildcard vhost at the END of your vhost configuration chain. On every request, apache has to scan its internal list of vhosts for an appropriate match. If it thinks it finds a match, then it'll use that vhost to serve the request, no matter how "wrong" it might be. So add a wildcard generic vhost at the end, to catch any "unknown" hosts.

Comment: Thanks for the clue! Apache is kind of bizarre with its settings. I posted the full solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to fix this. Added zzz.conf (so it's read last in alphabetical order in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/). This just leads to a directory with a file that says "Error."

Here's what I put in zzz.conf:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerAlias *
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</virtualhost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAlias *
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: lifesaver, I struggled 7 hours today. Thanks you so much : )